# Purging Azure SQL logs and backups after enabling Always Encrypted

Tags: sql-server, azure, encryption, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I am enabling Always Encrypted on an Azure SQL Database on a column. I need all of the past logs and backups to be purged from existence so as to not leak the old unencrypted version. What logs/backups exist in Azure SQL that would need to be removed in this case, and what is the recommended path to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to create a new database resource with AE enabled, move data to it and erase (delete) the "old" resource.